# Examples of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I would like to apologize in advance for this trivial question!

Does constant functions $u \equiv C$ and, in partucular, $u \equiv 0$ belong to $W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Update 2:

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded open set. 
I wonder whether $\exists \{u_i\}_{0}^{\infty} \subset C_{0}^{\infty},\mbox{ such that } u_i \rightarrow u \mbox{ in } W^{1,2}$?

Comment: The constant function on what space?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange! No need to apologize. In general, you'll get best results by making sure that you give meanings to all symbols, and a little context to your problem (e.g., "In the vector space $\mathbb R^n$, must every subspace have a finite basis?" is a perfectly good, although simple, question.)

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Non-zero constant functions DO NOT BELONG to $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Q2. The space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is defined as the «completion» of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ with norm
$$
\|u\|_{W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)}=\left(\int_\Omega\big(u^2(x)+\big|\nabla u(x)\big|^2\big)\,dx\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Thus, indeed, every element of $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ can be $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)}-$approximated by functions in 
$C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, even if $\Omega$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You can characterize $W^{1,2}_0$ as "the 'compactly supported' $L^2$ functions that have $L^2$ weak derivatives." Since the weak derivatives of a constant function are all zero, hence $L^2$, the answer to your question is the answer to, "are constant functions compactly supported $L^2$?" This is never true unless the constant is zero.

Comment: He asks if they lie in $W^{1,2}_0$ not $W^{1,2}$. In which case the answer is no unless $C=0$.

Comment: Ah! I missed the ${}_0$! Editing accordingly.